# Feincms, list of created pages with specific template

Tags: django, django-templates, feincms

I'm using feincms for django framework, and i need to get the list of pages that uses specific template.

-OR-

List of pages from specific hierarchy, i.e:

- main
- --1st
- --2nd
- --3d
- --etc.

Examples suggested in docs doesn't work, please help.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just filter by `template_key`?

```
from feincms.modules.page.models import Page
Page.objects.filter(template_key='homepage')
```

In order to filter by level, use the [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.io/django-mptt/models.html#setting-up-a-django-model-for-mptt) attributes:

```
Page.objects.filter(level=1)
```